# Проблема с opencv

Tags: python, opencv, screenshots, type-error

Вот код

```
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot(

    region=(first_screen_click[0],
            first_screen_click[1], 
            second_screen_click[0],
            second_screen_click[1]))

screenshot = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screenshot), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)


gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(screenshot, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

И ошибка

```
screenshot = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screenshot), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде работает

```py
>>> import pyautogui
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import cv2
>>> s = pyautogui.screenshot()
>>> n = np.array(s)
>>> cv_screenshot = cv2.cvtColor(n, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
>>> cv_screenshot.size
19353600
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Проблема оказалось в том, что сюда

```
region=(first_screen_click[0],
        first_screen_click[1], 
        second_screen_click[0],
        second_screen_click[1]))
```

Я подавал не верные координаты. Из-за этого ругался пайтон, что ожидал другие данные! Спасибо!